# Joomla 1.5 password check

Tags: php, joomla

I've inherited a joomla 1.5 site that has a reset password component that isn't functioning optimally. ATM I'm able to have password resets sent to the user inputted email, but the component is missing a function that checks against existing users to see if the email is valid. I'm rather new to PHP, so I'm not 100% sure how to introduce an additional if statement.

Here's how's it looking so far:

```
public function submitemail() {
    $db = JFactory::getDBO() ;
    $requestedEmail =   JRequest::getVar('emailaddr' , '') ;
    $db->setQuery('select id , username, name, email from #__users where block = 0  and email = "'.$requestedEmail.'"') ;
    if( $user =  $db->loadObject() )  {

        // Make sure the user isn't a Super Admin.
        $juser = JFactory::getUser($user->id) ;
        //joomla 1.6 and 1.5 check  
        if ($juser->authorize('core.admin') || $juser->usertype == 'Super Administrator') {
            $this->setRedirect( 'index.php?option=com_resetpassword'  , 'Email is not valid' ) ;        
        }
        else {          
            $result = $this->sendPasswordResetEmail( $user ) ;
            $this->setRedirect( 'index.php?option=com_resetpassword&layout=success'  //, 'Please check your email and follow the instructions to reset your password ' 
                ) ;
        }
    }
    else {
        $this->setRedirect( 'index.php?option=com_resetpassword'  );
    }
}
```

And I happened across a related post where I found this snippet. How would I go about checking against email addresses that are currently in my database against the user inputted email for the reset?

```
function validate()
{ jimport('joomla.mail.helper');
$valid = true;
 if ($this->_data->email && !JMailHelper::isEmailAddress($this->_data->email))
{           
     $this->_app->enqueueMessage(JText::_('Invalid Email Address'),'error');                       
     $valid = false;           
}   
return $valid; 
}
```

Comment: Is this code from a file on the `com_users` folder?

Comment: No, it's from the com_resetpassword folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is actually exactly what it is doing already. The top loads the row for the user based on the email address that is submitted:

```
$requestedEmail =   JRequest::getVar('emailaddr' , '') ;
$db->setQuery('select id , username, name, email from #__users where block = 0  and email = "'.$requestedEmail.'"') ;
if( $user =  $db->loadObject() )  {
    ...
```

All you likely need to do is add a message for when this fails to the else statement at the bottom:

```
else {
    $this->_app->enqueueMessage(JText::_('Invalid Email Address'),'error');
    $this->setRedirect( 'index.php?option=com_resetpassword'  );
}
```

If `$this->_app` isn't set, you should be able to get that by using this instead:

```
JFactory::getApplication()->enqueueMessage(JText::_('Invalid Email Address'),'error');
```

Comment: so would it look like so? `else {
   JFactory::getApplication()->enqueueMessage(JText::_('Invalid Email Address'),'error');
   $this->setRedirect( 'index.php?option=com_resetpassword'  );
   
   
     }`